# Scanner is skipping text file lines

Tags: java, file

I'm new to java and I need help with this problem I encountered. This class reads data from text file and adds it to the array Movie. The problem is that when it reads the text file, it skips every other line.

```
public class ReadFile{
private File f;
Scanner sc;
int index;

public ReadFile(){
    f = new File("db.txt");
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An Error occured, File couldn't be opened.");
    }
}

public int FileRead(Movie[] film, int index){
    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    this.index = index;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            film[index] = new Movie();
            film[index].setTitle(sc.next());
            film[index].setYear(sc.next());
            film[index].setRuntime(sc.next());
            film[index].setActorOne(sc.next());
            film[index].setActorTwo(sc.next());
            film[index].setDirector(sc.next());
            if(sc.hasNextLine()){
                sc.nextLine();
            }
            index++;
        }
    
    System.out.println("count is "+ index);
    sc.close();
    return index;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample piece of the file?

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` doesn't actually do what you think it does.

Furthermore, neither does `.useDelimiter(",")` - presumably, your file is something like:

```
Jurassic Park,1993,128,Jeff Goldblum,Jeff Goldblum's looks,Steven Spielberg
The Fly,1986,96,Jeff Goldblum,A fly,David Cronenberg
```

The problem is, computer is as computer does. You said the separator between tokens is a comma. And nothing else. So, this *whole thing* is a single token:

```
Steven Spielberg
The Fly
```

As in, `"Steven Spielberg\nThe Fly"` is what your `sc.next()` call returns for the first movie in the `setDirector` line. Seems stupid? Well, you told the computer: Tokens are things separated by commas. That whole thing is surrounded by commas so, you asked for it, you got it: That's the `next()` token in the file. Then you do an otherwise useless nextLine call which eats the rest of that `The Fly` line, thus, resulting in not only skipping every other movie, but having a mangled combo of the directory and the name of the movie on the next (otherwise skipped) line, mangled together. You know, like The Fly? Get it? [Note to self: It's a movie from 1987, no, they wont get it!]

The fix is possibly to tell scanner that either a comma *or* a newline counts as a separator; `.useDelimiter(",|\r?\n")` would do that. And forget about the `hasNextLine` + `nextLine` part, that does nothing, you should just get rid of that. Your code will fail if there's a 'broken' line in there (one that doesn't include precisely 5 commas), and that nextLine stuff isn't going to fix that problem, thus, get rid of it.

Alternatively, forget scanner - read line by lines using e.g. `Files.readAllLines`, then process line-by-line, using `.split(",")` to break it into parts.